# SQL Select Until value = my value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello i got this problem. Im trying to make SQL command that will Select count of items while it got status 0.

```
Name |   TimeStarted  | Status
Job1 |    210161      |   0
Job1 |    210160      |   0
Job1 |    210159      |   0
Job1 |    210158      |   1
Job1 |    210157      |   0
Job2 |    210156      |   1
Job2 |    210155      |   1
Job3 |    210154      |   1
```

On this example result of the Select should be something like this.

```
Name  | Job Count
Job1  |     3 
Job2  |     0
```

Point of this script is count number of failed jobs since their last successful launch. Thank you for your help

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  As such, there is no ordering to the tables.

Comment: right, you have an ordering criteria?

Comment: Is it normal that all your rows have the same `TimeStarted` value?  I was expecting that `TimeStarted` would define the ordering of your rows.  But based on your sample data, doesn't look that way.

Comment: aa yeah that was mistake made by me. This is just sample data. Those items are ordered by name and time started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
select t1.Name, count(t2.Name)
from (
  select Name, max(TimeStarted) as LastSuccessTime
  from TableX
  where Status = 1
  group by Name
) t1
left join TableX t2
on t1.Name = t2.Name
and t1.LastSuccessTime < t2.TimeStarted
group by t1.Name
```

Demo: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/093ae/5)

I'm sure there are edge cases that you may need to consider, such as, what happens if a job has never had a successful run, etc.  But at least it should get you going.

**EDIT**

I actually think that Gordon Linoff's query is more straight-forward than mine.  I just hadn't realized that it was missing a tiny condition to make it work properly.

Here is his query with the missing condition, and adapted to your data:

```
select t1.name, count(*) - 1
from tableX t1
where t1.TimeStarted >= (select max(t2.TimeStarted)
                         from tableX t2
                         where t2.Name = t1.Name
                         and t2.status = 1)
group by t1.name;
```

Demo: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/093ae/11)

Comment: Thank you thats what i wanted.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a fixed version of Gordon Linoff's query.  I think his approach is cleaner than my initial answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some sort if id to specify the ordering:

```
select name, count(*) - 1
from table t
where t.id <= (select min(id) from table t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.status <> 0)
group by name;
```

The `<=` is just to include rows where there are no initial 0s.

Comment: Wll i got IDs but they are varchar values like "42D03061-0CB1-4D2E-80C2-5D7E9D894F77" so cant order by ID. Only values containing number are job_time and job_date that got timestamp value.

Comment: This is the best solution I think.  However, the subquery is missing the following condition: `and t2.name = t.name`.